# OData - Greater than or Equals to Now() Minus 2

Tags: odata

Totally stuck here!  Been through many Google pages, wondering if someone can assist me.

I'm trying to pull data via OData into SQL however I'm struggling on being able to get the URI correct.  I don't want to pull a full table as I'd like to do an incremental load based on the last time the row was updated.

```
Metadata of Column: 
<Property Name="_UpdatedTime" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false"/>
```

In English, I'm trying to do the following in my $filter:

- _UpdatedTime greater than or equal to Now() minus 2 days

I have the following, however it is incorrect!

```
_UpdatedTime ge Edm.DateTimeOffset addDays('Now()', -2)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks hacky, but try this:

```
?$filter=_UpdatedTime sub now() ge duration'-P2D'
```

it means:

```
(updatedTime - now()) >= -2 days
```

that is equivalent to

```
updatedTime >= now() -2 days
```

Comment: Sadly didn't work :(  I get the error:  Invalid OData Request: Unsupported operator\\r\\nStatement: _UpdatedTime sub now() ge duration'-P2D'.  I'm starting to think it isn't possible sadly!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Vladimir's answer, the following query can also be used and is more easily readable in my opinion:

```
_UpdatedTime ge (now() sub duration'P2D')
```

This works in OData v4: http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_PrimitiveLiterals